# AvAudioRecorder stops/restart after recording just started

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

In an iOS 10.2 app, an AVAudioRecorder is set up to record, and display level metering:

```
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&error];
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
[recorder record];
```

When I start the recorder, I noticed that the vu-meter is not updated. I noticed that the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording: successfully:` method is called immediately after the recording has started. But the AVAudioRecorder still records after that. And the audio file can be saved and played.

More strangely, when I pause the recording and resume it, the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording: successfully:` is not fired as in the first case, and the recording resume with vu-meter updating.

Any idea of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are setting the AVPlayer, you have to keep in mind that only one instance can be done , either you can play the recorded audio or can run the recorder. so accordingly you have to manage the delegates and the AVPlayer configuration settings.

hope it works.

Comment: I dont use any AVPlayer when I am in recording phase, and only one instance of AudioRecorder. I checked that. Compiled some time ago under iOS 8, I didn't have this strange behavior, while using exactly the same code in the recorder section of my app... Running this old version on iOS10.2 works with no trouble...

Comment: Solved after re-reading your answer: in fact, the audioRecorderDidFinishRecording: successfully: is fired with a delay (seems to be longer when app compiled against iOS10.2). As I use a temporary recorder to display signal level, and stop/release it before creating the actual recorder, the method was fired after this recorder has begun recording, thus interfering! Thanks Aman!